# How to start a thread for an operation at each iteration of for loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, selenium, for-loop

I am using a `for` loop which run for 10 times and in each iteration driver move to different URL and loads a file which took 4 minutes to complete all 10  downloads. I was wondering if I could implement multi-threading in a `for` loop so that it starts a different thread for each iteration to execute the download process.

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(setChromePref(URL[i]));
        obj_SjStrore = new SjStrore(driver);
        driver.click.findelements(By.xpath("xpath string").click;
        driver.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the site rules, and also: [HOw to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You won't get direct answers to questions over here; write a code and if you face a trouble in that then we're here to solve it for you.

Comment: Yes, you can. You create a new `Thread` in each iteration, provide each with a `Runnable` to do a certain job, start the thread, store all the thread objects in some collection, and after the loop you wait for all the stored threads to finish.

Comment: Or, use an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ParallelDownload implements Runnable {

    private String url;
    private String xpath;

    public ParallelDownload(String url, String xpath) {
        super();
        this.url = url;
        this.xpath = xpath;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url[] = new String[10];
        String xpath[] = new String[10];

        // create thread executor with pool of 10 threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Initialize a thread and execute
            Runnable worker = new ParallelDownload(url[i], xpath[i]);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        // wait till all the threads stops executing
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }

    }

}
```